# Reduce memory usage in R Kaggle

Tags: r

I'm trying to make some different analysis (Principal components, factor analysis, clusters etc.) on the dataset:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/ashrae-energy-prediction

The issue is that I try to combine 3 datasets into one dataset to make the analysis and I use all memory at the site.

Code so far:

```
## Import data
building_metadata <- read.csv("../input/ashrae-energy-prediction/building_metadata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",dec = ".")
train <- read.csv("../input/ashrae-energy-prediction/train.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",dec = ".")
weather_train <- read.csv("../input/ashrae-energy-prediction/weather_train.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",dec = ".")

#Combining data
#1) building_metadata and train (with building_id)
#2) merged.data and weather_train (with timestamp)
merged.data <- merge(building_metadata, train, by="building_id")
data <- merge(merged.data, weather_train, by="timestamp")
```

Question: How can I combine the datasets without using all the memory?

Alternatively is it possible to make the analysis without combining the data?

Comment: Moving to `data.table` should reduce memory usage quite a lot, possibly `dplyr` will be sufficient. In this case `data.table` will be simpler however, as it becomes using `setDT([data here])` before merging, and if you're uncomfortable with the package interface then just using `setDF([data here])`  after merging.

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting, have you tried merging with smaller subsets of the data? You can find out what is causing the explosive growth (likely a cartesion/outer join) and fix it before going on to the larger sets. If you provide representative output from each CSV (that includes in-common join-field values), we might be able to help. (I suggest either raw CSV or the output from `dput(head(x,n))` where `n` is small enough to fit here but *just large enough* to get the point across.)

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I tried the proposed ideas, but obtain the same situation. I tried switching to Python and use pandas dataframe, and a data reduction function, which reduced the datasets by 65%, however once again I end in the same situation. I also switched to Google Coolab, which provides 12GB RAM vs Kaggles 5 RAM. But it is still not enough.